# Android: Rxjava and Intent Service

Tags: android, asynchronous, rx-java, intentservice

I am fairly new to asynchronous programming. I am making android application and currently using `Intent Service`. Intent Service will be called from Broadcast receiver when `Wi-Fi is turned on`. In receiver it gets all the data from Database and send it to Intent Service from where service call the method to post it to the server. I have been reading about RX java for reactive programming.

**Do I need to use RX java instead of intent service to manage the concurrency and delays of *net* and *Db*? Does this make sense?**

Comment: Intent Service itself is a worker Thread. For your instance, you can simply go ahead using the Intentservice. But learning RxJava/RxAndroid is advantageous

Comment: @TerrilThomas Thanks. Can you please explain a bit in which scenarios RXjava is best to use?

Comment: RxAndroid uses RxJava. It uses Observer Pattern and is attached to the main Thread for showing the UI. So even if you navigate across the activities it instance is maintained against the mainLooper. If you need to know more then read this http://reactivex.io/intro.html

Comment: Thanks I will read it now